# Change Leaflet Default Markers with Custom Markers

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am seeking advice/help on how to change the Leaflet default markers (blue markers) to a customs marker.  I searched here at StackOverFlow and I found a couple of ways to do this but I can't seem to make any of them work. The closes I have gotten, I was able to add a new icon on my map but not able to change the default icons to my custom icon(s).  I'm using leaflet omnivore because I enjoy working with csv files, so this method is a great fit for me.  Also I'm a big D3 user and I'm trying to learn something new. Below is the code I'm using. However my ultimate goal is to replace the default blue markers with a mix of different markers/icons like I can achieve with D3 (icon file types like svg, png, jpg, or gif etc).  I appreciate any help and thank you in advance.

```
omnivore.csv('data/pointData5.csv')
.on('ready', function(layer) {

/*Couldn't get this to work*/
var tankIcon = L.icon({
iconUrl: 'graphic/tank.png',
iconSize: [50,40]
}); 
L.geoJson(layer,{
pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng){
  return L.marker(latlng,{icon: ratIcon});
}
}).addTo(map);

/*Only place one icon on the map and changing all the default markers*/
var markers = new L.LayerGroup();   
var myIcon = L.icon({ 
    iconUrl: 'graphic/tank.png',
    iconSize: [20, 20],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
    shadowSize: [68, 95],
    shadowAnchor: [22, 94]
});

marker = L.marker([50.505, 30.57], {icon: myIcon}).bindPopup("Hi there").addTo(markers);
map.addLayer(markers);

/*This code works perfect - providing me what I was hoping for*/
        this.eachLayer(function(marker) {
        marker.bindPopup(marker.toGeoJSON().properties.imageTitle + ', ' + "<br />" + marker.toGeoJSON().properties.discrip + ', ' + "<br /><a class='fancybox-thumb'   rel='fancybox-button'  rel='fancybox-thumb' data-fancybox-group='gallery' href='graphic/" + marker.toGeoJSON().properties.popup +"'><img src='graphic/" + marker.toGeoJSON().properties.popup + "' style='width:100%' /></a>");
    });
})
.addTo(map);
```

Comment: As for reading the GeoJSON data associated to your Leaflet Marker, you can simply use `marker.feature.properties` instead of calling the method `marker.toGeoJSON()`, which performs much more operations under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I researched a little more and found the answer to my question, how to add custom markers to my map using omnivore Leaflet/Mapbox.  If someone needs to do this, below script worked for me.

```
//set up a customized icon to use for the point data
var customIcon = L.icon({
iconUrl: 'graphic/tank.png',
iconSize: [18, 9], //size of the icon in pixels
iconAnchor: [9, 9], //point of the icon which will correspond to marker's
location (the center)
popupAnchor: [0, 0] //point from which the popup should open relative to 
the iconAnchor
});


omnivore.csv('data/pointData5.csv')
.on('ready', function(layer) {
    this.eachLayer(function(marker) {
         //change the icons for each point on the map
        marker.setIcon(customIcon);
         //create popup with text and image - click image in popup, large  
image displays in fancybox
        var popupText =
             marker.bindPopup(marker.toGeoJSON().properties.imageTitle +
 ', ' + "<br />" + marker.toGeoJSON().properties.discrip + ', ' + "<br
 /><a class='fancybox-thumb'    rel='fancybox-button'  rel='fancybox-
thumb' data-fancybox-group='gallery' href='graphic/" + 
marker.toGeoJSON().properties.popup +"'><img src='graphic/" + 
marker.toGeoJSON().properties.popup + "' style='width:100%' /></a>");
});
}).addTo(map);
```